# Build Android News Recommendation app

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design

Please I am interested in building a news recommendation app that will be powered by artificial intelligence. I have being making a whole lot of research on this and will be glad if somebody can tell what is needed to build such app in Android.

It is something similar to this [app](https://www.recent.io/)

Comment: Welcome to AI!  If I understand your question, you are looking for advice on what type of method would be suitable for this problem?  The question might benefit from a title such as *"AI methods for News Recommendation App? (Android OS)"*  Also, you should probably indicate whether all functions will be local to the mobile device, or if it will be able to take advantage of networked processing and storage (databases).

Comment: Actually I am looking for advice and will be glad to get one.  Meanwhile, I am open to whichever methods that work either locally on the phone or through network processes.  Definitely, I would want to host my database in a server somewhere else, not on the phone

Comment: Let's get serious here.and those upvotes should tell us why?